# Mutuating Tables With Triggers?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am using a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger on an table and want to query the same table in the trigger.
The trigger is FOR EACH ROW.

When compiled the trigger is complied successfully without error and warnnings and is in Valid state.
But the trigger does not execute the code from where i am querying for this  table and after.

All the code is doing is checking if the customer has already used the debitnote#(Stored in Attribute1) or not. If it has already used then throw error else proceed.

I am unable to do this. Is it mutuatuing Table Error?.Any Help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER APPS_APPL.XX_OZF_DBTNUM_INS_TRG


BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON OZF_CLAIM_LINES_ALL
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.org_id = 43)
DECLARE
   ln_cust_account_id    NUMBER;
   ln_debit_cust_count   NUMBER;
   le_claim_invalid      EXCEPTION;
   lv_attribute1         VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   --Get Customer account Id for this new ClaimID
   SELECT cust_account_id
     INTO ln_cust_account_id
     FROM ozf_claims_all
    WHERE claim_id = :NEW.CLAIM_ID;

   --Get Count of Records That this customer has same debitNote#
   SELECT COUNT (ocla.claim_line_id)
INTO ln_debit_cust_count
  FROM ozf_claims_all oca, ozf_claim_lines_all ocla
 WHERE     oca.claim_id = ocla.claim_id
       AND oca.cust_account_id = ln_cust_account_id
       AND ocla.debitnum = :NEW.debit_number;   

   --If count is more then 0 then throw error else proceed
   IF ln_debit_cust_count > 0
   THEN
      RAISE le_claim_invalid;
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN le_claim_invalid
   THEN
      fnd_message.set_name ('OZF', 'XX_OZF_DEBITNUM_VALIDATION');
      fnd_msg_pub.ADD;
      RAISE fnd_api.g_exc_error;
END;
/
```

Comment: Avoid using    `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;` then you will see error.

Comment: `WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL` is itself a bug. See [WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL – A bug](http://lalitkumarb.wordpres.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: Thanks i will remove that part of code. But Still need your help in getting this error resolved.

Comment: Remove it, compile it and post the complete error stack. Compile time errors are different from run time errors.

Comment: Hi,  I Did the changes. Cursor compiled and no errors were thrown. Records were inserted in table, There were no runtime errors.

Comment: We can't see what data is already in the tables or what data you are adding, so we can't see if the trigger *should* throw an exception; or even attempt to fire since it's restricted by `org_id`. Have you run your queries separately to see what counts they actually get?

Comment: Yes Alex, Actaully there are 9 Record count tat have same debit note# for an specific customer. If I comment the 2nd select statement then i am getting the defined error under eXception and code is working.
Its just the 2nd select statement that is wrong.
I guess its because i cannot acces the table on which i have trigger.

Comment: Trigger is on OZF_CLAIM_LINES_ALL table and in 2nd statement also i am querying OZF_CLAIM_LINES_ALL table.

Comment: [This question on dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29244/why-am-i-not-getting-a-mutating-table-error-in-trigger) indicates that under some circumstances (and I'm not clear on what those circumstances are) the ORA-04091 is not raised for single-row INSERTs, but is raised for multi-row INSERTs (e.g. INSERT...SELECT...). Interesting...

Comment: @BobJarvis You can post it as a question .. what do you think ?

Comment: @Moudiz - it's a pretty well-known thing, and the DBA question seems to cover it well. The mutating table error is about seeing an inconsistent set of data. With a single-row insert you know the state. With multi-row the state is indeterminate from each row's point of view as you don't know which other rows already 'exist' at that point.

Comment: @user3322633 - how are you getting the exception if you don't do the count? Does your `ozf_claim_lines_all` really have columns called `debit_number` *and* `debitnum`, and if so which are you supposed to be checking? Can you add the table definition and sample data you're using, and the inserts you're doing after the trigger is created?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to make sure that there are not multiple rows in OZF_CLAIM_LINES_ALL for the same CLAIM_ID and DEBIT_NUMBER.

If this is true than you can add an unique key constraint on table OZF_CLAIM_LINES_ALL on the columns CLAIM_ID and DEBITNUM.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

If this is not an option and the only option is by using a trigger, you can work around it by using a row trigger (like the one you have) and instead of select from the same table you can add it into a temp table. Then use a statement trigger to select from the temp table and the table you want to update. That is where you can raise your error if count > 0.